# Installing java 1.6 when 1.7 already installed?

Tags: java, alternatives

I have java 1.7 installed and I am trying to install java 1.6.

I have updated java_home and path variable pointing to the new location, also ran these commands.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac
```

My java -version shows me java 1.6 but when I run java class_name, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: three : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

When I run the command sudo update-alternatives --config java

```
 Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45/                     1         manual mode
* 3            /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java             1         manual mode
  4            /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/bin/java             1         manual mode
```

Can anyone tell me what I am I missing?

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Since you're using `update-alternatives`, I assume a Debian derived Linux distribution but which one?  Also, please [edit] and add the output of `type java` and `java -version`.

Answer (score 0):

You need Java 7 to run class files with version 51.0 so you either need to recompile the class or upgrade to Java 7.

Java has lots of links in /etc/alternatives, but there is a tool called `update-java-alternatives` in the java-common package which makes it easier to maintain them all. That way you don't end up using one version of javac and another of java.